# Lua - limit function parameters to a certain type

Tags: function, lua, game-engine, lua-table, love2d

I have a function called particle.new, and one of the parameters is called "colour". I need this to always be a table, but it isn't. This gives me an error because I'm using it with a function called love.graphics.setColor(), and I need to give it a table. I'm using my colour variable with it, which gives me an error because it is expecting a table and it thinks that colour isn't a table. Anyway, here's my code.

```
particle = {}
particle.__index = particle

function particle.new (x, y, colour, mass, drag)
  local self = setmetatable({}, particle)
  self.x, self.y, self.colour, self.mass, self.drag = x, y, colour, mass, drag
  return self
end

function particle:draw ()
  prevColor = love.graphics.getColor()
  love.graphics.setColor(self.colour)
  love.graphics.point(self.x, self.y)
  love.graphics.setColor(prevColor)
end

function particle:update ()

end

function love.load()
  gravity = -9.32
  particles = {}
  table.insert(particles, particle.new(50,50,{255, 0, 0, 255},1,0.2))
end

function love.draw()
  for i = 1, table.maxn(particles) do
    particles[i]:draw()
  end
end
```

By the way, I'm using the Love2D game engine.

Comment: So, what's the question? You want to know how to limit the parameters to a certain type? You can use `assert` in combination with `type(colour) == 'table'`.

Comment: Replace `prevColor = love.graphics.getColor()` with `local prevColor = {love.graphics.getColor()}`

Comment: I need to make it so the colour parameter in particle.new can only be a table.

Comment: Oh wait, @EgorSkriptunoff , your idea worked! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: To state what may or may not be obvious: You can't limit the type of an argument passed to a function but you can raise an error inside the function.

Comment: Sorry, @ZacG, I'm too lazy... ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with self.colour not being a table, it's with this line

```
prevColor = love.graphics.getColor()
```

When you do that, `prevColor` is only getting one of the four returned values.
The solution to this is to enclose the function call in a table, so that all 4 values are kept. (Like what @EgorSkriptunoff said)

```
prevColor = {love.graphics.getColor()}
```

As for your question:
Use `assert` and `type` to check the variable type

```
assert(type(colour)=="table", "-Error message goes here-")
```

Do note however, assert will throw an error which will bring up the blue love2d screen and stop your program from running.